# How to monitor CPU utilization using POSIX clock() function during runtime?

Tags: c, time, embedded, posix, clock

Is there any reliable method how a program can measure its CPU utilization during its runtime?

I probably have to use a POSIX [clock()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) function from [time.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time.h). The idea is first to use some milliseconds to set an idle CPU load (step A), then full CPU load (step B), then to start a program and call clock() constantly. Thus, I can calculate CPU utilization relative to a calculated on step A and step B to monitor a CPU utilization in the percentage. I assume that all other background processes are ignored.

However, I am not sure, how to implement these step A and step B, say idle() and full_load() functions properly using only C89 and POSIX?

Comment: are you measuring the CPU utilization of the process you are in, or a separate process?

Comment: @Spudd86: my own process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say "full_load", and you only need a single CPU or virtual core under load, a simple tight loop will do the trick.  Granted, it won't use all the transistors on the chip (i.e., we're not talking about a burn-in test for "full-load"), but it will, for the scheduled time-slice it gets of the CPU, use all the available clock-cycles with no syscalls that would give up control to the kernel and possibly cause the executing thread to be re-scheduled for later.  Also you could use an alarm with a signal handler in order to exit from the loop.  So that would let you run the loop for approximately a second of execution time (alarms aren't exactly time-accurate ... they're close, but not down to the clock-cycle).

In addition, for the "idle" load portion, you could do the same thing, but using a `sigsuspend()` instead of a tight loop, that would wait for the alarm to go off.

So your code could look something like the following:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static sig_atomic_t alarm_flag = 1;

void alarm_handler(int arg)
{
    alarm_flag = 0;
}

clock_t idle()
{
    //setup the alarm flag
    alarm_flag = 1;

    //setup the signal masks
    sigset_t old_signal_set;
    sigset_t new_signal_set;

    sigemptyset(&old_signal_set);
    sigemptyset(&new_signal_set);

    //block the alarm signal
    sigaddset(&new_signal_set, SIGALRM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &new_signal_set, &old_signal_set);

    //setup the alarm
    alarm(1);

    clock_t time_before = clock();

    //sit idle while we wait for the alarm to go off
    while(alarm_flag)
        sigsuspend(&old_signal_set);

    clock_t time_after = clock();

    //restore the old signal mask
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &old_signal_set, NULL);

    return time_after - time_before;
}

clock_t full_load()
{
    //set the alarm signal
    alarm_flag = 1;

    //set the 1-second alarm
    alarm(1);

    clock_t time_before = clock();

    //loop until the alarm goes off
    while(alarm_flag);

    clock_t time_after = clock();

    return time_after - time_before;
}

int main()
{
    //setup the signal handler for the alarm
    sigset(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);

    //call the functions
    clock_t idle_time = idle();
    clock_t load_time = full_load();

    //... do whatever else you need to-do with this info
    printf("Idle Time: %d\n", (int)idle_time);
    printf("Load Time: %d\n", (int)load_time);

    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that according to the POSIX standard, there should be 1 million clocks per second as the time-base for the the `clock_t` value, so you should see the number returned for the "full_load" that is close to that number since we're going "full-load" for approximately a second.  Idle load should be very small (of course).  Here's numbers I generated on my Mac Pro:

```
Idle Time: 31
Load Time: 1000099
```

So that seems somewhat in-line with what you're looking for as far as knowing how many clock cycles you may see returned from `clock()`.  I would of course run this multiple times and take an average to get a better indicator of the variance you might see.

Answer (score 2):

I thought this is covered by CLOCK_VIRTUAL (BSD/HP-UX) or CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID on linux for clock_gettime(2).

Comment: don't you mean `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`

Comment: No, I meant CLOCK_VIRTUAL. Apparently you can only count on CLOCK_REALTIME as per [SusV2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/clock_gettime.html) and I was looking at BSD and picked the wrong one. Linux uses your constant, HP-UX also uses CLOCK_VIRTUAL. Editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify the version of POSIX, but if you are using C89, it must be pretty old. POSIX.1-2001 aka SUSv3 requires C99 and there is also POSIX.1-2008.

Calibration seems unnecessary; just compare the values returned to monotonic (better, but may not be available) or wall clock time. For `clock()`, use the `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` define (this is guaranteed to be one million if the system supports the XSI option, but not if it is just POSIX).

Consider `getrusage()` instead of `clock()` for more accuracy and flexibility.

The function `getrusage()` was under the XSI option in earlier POSIX versions; the change history says it was introduced in Issue 4 Version 2 (SUSv1) and was moved to the base in Issue 5 (SUSv2) but there are still XSI markings on it. In any case it is pretty common as it is a 4.2BSD function.

Another option is the `times()` function.